# exchange data and events between two components in sync

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm new here, starting some code with Angular 7, and I have a problem.
I created two components and a service. The data is retrieved by the service when a button is clicked in component `searchbar`. I want to show it in `search-res` view. 
The service has data to take from the `searchbar` component

This is the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }



  getData( input:string ):Observable<any>
  {
   return this.http.get<any>('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q='+input+'&apiKey=b9d34afdf37948cda401c3dc0afe1189')
  }

}
```

I am unsure how to do this in these components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchbar',
  templateUrl: './searchbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchbar.component.css']
})
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public inData : string ;  

  constructor(private data : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**search-res component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-res',
  templateUrl: './search-res.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-res.component.css']
})
export class SearchResComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

please help !

Comment: may use stackbliz to show us your project even you should include your templates for the components

Comment: This will be useful and answers your question :) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

As with most everything in coding, you have several options. And it is not clear how the two components you defined (SearchbarComponent and SearchResComponent) are related.

**Subscribe from both components**

This is the easiest way to get the data into both components and does not require any relationship between them. But it *does* then get the data twice. So this may be a good choice to "get started" and build a working prototype, but may not be good for a production solution.

**Subscribe in one component and pass the data to the other**

This option is also pretty straight forward, but depends on how the components are related.

If one component is a child component of the other ... that is to say that it resides on the other, like this:

Component 1's html

```
<component2's selector></component2's selector>
```

Then you can pass data to the child component using `Input` properties.

**Build a data cache**

You can get the data one time and cache it in a service. This option breaks down into several more options.

You could define a simple property in your DataService that you can retrieve the data into and then manage the cache there.

OR you could define an HttpInterceptor and manage your cache there.

The downside of this approach is that you have to then manage the cache. If the user adds or deletes any items ... the cache needs to be invalidated. And after some amount of time, other users may have changed the data, so the cache should be invalidated.

**Use a state management library**

You could use a state management library (such as NgRx). It handles caching your data and provides it to any component that needs it. This is a great solution for a production-quality application ... but it is a bit intimidating for new Angular developers as it leverages complex features such as RxJS.

Each of these is a large topic ... let me know if there is one choice in particular you are interested in and I can provide some pointers to more information.

Comment: thank you ! i used BehaviorSubject from rxjs and it works well !